# Love2D, Threads execution and input

Tags: multithreading, lua, love2d

Please, i got a problem with Love2d thread functions, and i didnt find any examples or explanations i would understand anywhere.

first:
in main file i got:

```
thread1 = love.thread.newThread("ambient.lua")
thread2 = love.thread.newThread("ambient.lua")
thread1:start()
thread2:start()
```

ambient.lua contains:

```
random1 = love.math.random(1, 10)
gen1 = love.audio.newSource("audio/ambient/gen/a/gen_a_".."random1"..".mp3", 
"static")
gen1:setVolume(1.0)
gen1:setLooping(false)
gen1:play()
```

works fine, problem is that when i ask *var = Thread1:isRunning( )* in same step or with delay, when audio is playing and try to print it, it throws error (is supposedly null). when the audio finishes, i see that memory is cleared. also if i link *thread1:start()* to mouse click and then start it multiple times in short time, memory usage goes up like crazy, then after time similar to sample length it starts to decrease. question is, am i creating multiple threads? in that case did they even terminate properly after samples ended? or is the thread lifetime just 1-step long and i am only creating multiple audio sources playing with the same thread? is problem in the check itself?

next issue is that i need to use thread1:start() with values:

```
thread1:start(volume, sampleID)
```

and i have no clue how to addres them in the thread itself. guides and examples says "vararg" reference. i didnt see any decent explanation or any example containing "..." usage in variable input into threads. i am in need of example how to write it. even if this audio fiddle is not a great example, i will surely need it for AI. No need for complicated input, just simple x,y,size,target_x,target_y values.

Comment: `when i ask var = Thread1:isRunning( )`, did you mistyped here? Lua is case sensitive, `Thread1` is not the same as `thread1`. If you assigned to `thread1`, then `Thread1` doesn't exist, so you get error about nil.

Comment: ah, thanks. mistake in code. check works now and says that thread ends instantly, while samples keep playing then ends. with loops enabled, threads still ends instantly, while samples keep playing and adding up with new threads, resulting in some terrible results over time.

Comment: Love's audio player should live in its own thread. It doesn't matter from where you schedule new audio source, you can do it from the main thread (and probably you should), Love's player thread will continue with the data you fed to it.

Comment: about the varargs, or passing args to thread to be more precise... could i get a help with it? when i just type in arg into thread start like i wrote above, then try to use that variable in thread, it does nothing. and as i mentioned i didnt find and actual example in use how to do so.

Comment: seems like i need to figure out how channels work to be able to run any tests, where i got problem that with local this_thread = love.thread.getChannel(), the thread stops working. (this line added at start of thread)

Comment: actually there are so many problems i think i will exchange all data between threads through files. found only few usage examples for older love versions, without channel usage, where simply converting to similar new functions doesnt work. also the issue with getchannel solved, love._curthread doesnt crash thread so maybe it works... anyway... i need a full guide on thread/channel usage with examples, or its a no-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and i have no clue how to addres them in the thread itself. guides and
>   examples says "vararg" reference. i didnt see any decent explanation
>   or any example containing "..." usage in variable input into threads

You didn't read manuals enough. Every loaded Lua chunk (section 2.4.1 of Lua 5.1 manuals) is an anonymous function with variable number of arguments.
When you call `love.thread.newThread("ambient.lua")`, Love2D will create new chunk, so basic Lua rules applies to this case.
In your example, volume and sampleID parameters from within thread would be retrieved like this:

```
local volume, sampleID = ...

gen1 = love.audio.newSource(get_stream_by_id(sampleID), "static")
gen1:setVolume(volume)
gen1:setLooping(false)
gen1:play()
```

Comment: yay works perfectly. thanks. could you possibly also ansver how to send data back into main lua thread so i dont have to "figure it out"?